Evaluating $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}$
Hi I have this limit and I don't know how to conjugate a cubic root expression.Is that the same with square roots?I have the limit but I don't understand something.
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}$$
Do you conjugate this expression with $a+b$ and after that $a^3-b^3$ and $a^3+b^3$?
Is that how you solve it?
Is that possible?
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}\right)*\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}+\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}\right)*\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{((x+1)^3+1)((x-1)^3-1))}+\sqrt[3]{((x-1)^3-1)^2}\right)*\left(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{((x+1)^3+1)((x-1)^3-1))}+\sqrt[3]{((x-1)^3-1)^2}\right)$$
Can someone please help me?

Hint: $$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}.$$ Take $a=\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}$ and conclude.

@Surb so the steps which I took are wrong?

Not clear what you tried to do...

@Surb I wanted to conjugate the cube Root!

There are no conjugate for $\sqrt[3]a-\sqrt[3]b$ strictly talking, however, $\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}$ plays the same role than the conjugate of square root in the sense that $$(\sqrt[3]a-\sqrt[3]b)(\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2})=a-b.$$

@Surb but this video shows the opposite of what you said  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haOrYCvDo9Q

I may be wrong...

@Surb Oh sorry for the mistake.I had another limit with $$\frac{\sqrt{cos(x)}-\sqrt[3]cos(x)}{x^2}$$

@Surb In this exercise I used both a^2-b^2 and a^2+b^2 and after that a+b.This is what made me confused!

The conjugates for $1+\sqrt[3]b$ are $1+\zeta_3\sqrt[3]b$ and $1+\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]b$. Their product is $1+b$ and the product of the last two factors is $1+\sqrt[3]b+\sqrt[3]b^2$, so the algebra fits together. Note that for any irreducible polynomial, its roots are conjugates of each other.

Another way to use the binomial series is to leave the $(x\pm1)$ together, so one gets
$$
(x+1)\sqrt[3]{1+(x+1)^{-3}}-(x-1)\sqrt[3]{1-(x-1)^{-3}} \\
=(x+1)(1+\tfrac13(x+1)^{-3}+O((x+1)^{-6}))-(x-1)(1-\tfrac13(x-1)^{-3}+O((x-1)^{-6}))
$$
So everything goes to zero except for the leading terms, and they combine to
$$
(x+1)-(x-1)=2,
$$
which as a constant stays at that value in the limit.


Here is a better method to prove your limit. My previous answer while not completely incorrect, is not very strong due to certain approximations.

Playing with the squeeze theorem, we bound the $2$ cube roots in your limit as such:
$$x + 1 < \sqrt[3]{(x + 1)^3 + 1} < \sqrt{(x + 1)^2 + 1} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$x - 1 > \sqrt[3]{(x - 1)^3 - 1} > \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 - 1}, \quad  x > 2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
The reasoning behind the upper bound  of $\eqref{eq1}$ and lowerbound
of $\eqref{eq2}$ is due to the fact that they are asymptotic to $x + 1$ and $x - 1$ respectively.
We let $L = \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}$, and so,
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}x + 1 - (x - 1) < L < \lim_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}$$
We know LHS $ = 2$, so we only have to calculate RHS. Now, we can indeed use method of conjugates:
$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}-\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1} \iff \frac{(x + 1)^2 + 1 - (x - 1)^2 + 1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}}
\\\iff 2 \cdot \frac{2x + 1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}\left( 1 + \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 - 1}}\right)} 
\\\iff 2 \cdot \frac{2x + 1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 - 1}}}$$
So,
$$\text{RHS} = 2 \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{\sqrt{\frac{(2x + 1)^2}{x(x - 2)}}} \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{\frac{1}{ 1 + \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 2x + 2}{x(x - 2)}}}}
\\\text{RHS} = 2 \cdot \sqrt{\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{\left(\frac{25}{2(x - 2)} - \frac{1}{2x} + 4\right)}} \cdot \frac{1}{ 1 + \sqrt{\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{\left(\frac{5}{x - 2} - \frac{1}{x} + 1\right)}}}
\\= 2 \cdot \sqrt{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{1}} = 2$$
Therefore, $L$ must be $2$.

First of all, we will prove that, for any $\,x\geqslant2\,,\,$ it results that
$\boxed{\;\\\;\;0<x\!\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}}\,\right]\!<\dfrac2{(x\!-\!1)^2}\quad\color{blue}{(*)}\;\;\\}$
Indeed, for any $\,x\geqslant2\,,\,$ it follows that
$\begin{align}0&=x\!\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}\,\right]\underset{\overbrace{\,1-\frac1{(x+1)^3}>1-\frac1{(x-1)^3}\,}}{<}\\[3pt]&<x\!\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}}\,\right]\underset{\overbrace{\,\sqrt[3]y\geqslant y\,\text{ for all }\,y\in[0,1]\,\\\,y\,=\,1-\frac1{(x-1)^3}\,\in\,[0,1)}\,}{\leqslant}\\[3pt]&\leqslant x\!\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-\left(\!1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}\!\right)\right]\underset{\overbrace{\,\sqrt[3]{1-\frac1{(x+1)^3}}\,<\,1\;}}{<}\\[3pt]&<\!x\!\left[1\!-\!\left(\!1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}\!\!\right)\!\right]\!=\!\dfrac x{(x\!-\!1)^3}\!\leqslant\!\dfrac{2(x\!-\!1)}{(x\!-\!1)^3}\!=\!\dfrac2{(x\!-\!1)^2}\,.\end{align}$
From $(*)$, by applying the Squeeze Theorem, we get that
$\boxed{\;\\\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}x\!\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}}\,\right]\!=0\qquad\color{blue}{(**)}\;\;\\}$
Now, we will calculate the following limit :
$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\bigg[\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3-1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}\bigg]=$
$=\!\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left[(x\!+\!1)\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-(x\!-\!1)\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}}\,\right]\!=$
$=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} x\!\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}-\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}}\,\right]+\\\;\;+\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left[\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!+\!1)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{1\!-\!\dfrac1{(x\!-\!1)^3}}\,\right]\!\underset{\overbrace{\;\text{ because of }\,(**)\;}}{=}$
$=0+2=2\,.$


You are dealing with cube roots, not square roots. Instead of trying to square the terms its easier to analyze the behavior of the functions near $x = \infty$.

Particularly, observe that $\sqrt[3]{(x + 1)^3 + 1} > \sqrt[3]{(x + 1)^3} = x + 1$ and $\sqrt[3]{(x - 1)^3 - 1} < \sqrt[3]{(x - 1)^3} = x - 1$. However, for large enough $x$, both the latter $\pm 1$ barely change the result: $\sqrt[3]{(\infty \pm 1)^3 \pm 1} \approx \sqrt[3]{(\infty \pm 1)^3}$.
To be more concrete, we can use the Laurent expansion of both cube roots to show that $x + 1$ and $x - 1$ are oblique asymptotes of $\sqrt[3]{(x + 1)^3 + 1}$ and $\sqrt[3]{(x - 1)^3 - 1}$ respectively.
Using $\sqrt[3]{(x + 1)^3 + 1}$ as an example, map $x \to 1/x$ to get the series expansion at $x = \infty$; $\sqrt[3]{(x + 1)^3 + 1} \approx x + 1 + \dfrac{1}{3x^2} + O\left(\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right)$. Observe that $\dfrac{1}{3x^2}  + O\left(\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.
And so
$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}}
\\=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}{x + 1 - (x - 1)}
\\= 2$$

Why isn't the answer $0$? As $x\to\infty$, the $x^3$ terms dominate so you end up with $\sqrt[3]{x^3}-\sqrt[3]{x^3}=0$

@jonnybolton16 Your logic says $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1)-(n-1) = 0.$

So why can we throw away the $\pm1$ outside of the cube, but not the one inside?

@johnnybolton Because for large $y$,$$\sqrt[3]{y^3\pm1}\in y\pm\frac13y^{-2}+O(y^{-5}).$$In this problem, we take a $O(1)$ difference of two choices of $y$.

Let us avoid writing ugly cube roots and instead use the symbols $a, b$ to denote the two cube roots occurring in question and we have to find the limit of $a-b$ as $x\to\infty$. We have $$a^3-b^3=(x+1)^3-(x-1)^3+2=6x^2+4$$ and further $a/x\to 1,b/x\to 1$. Thus $$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{6x^2+4}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$ and the above can be rewritten as $$\frac{6+(4/x^2)}{(a/x)^2+(a/x)(b/x)+(b/x)^2}$$ and this tends to $$\frac{6+0}{1^2+1\cdot 1+1^2}=2$$

We know that for $x \ge  0$
$$
\cases{
x+1\le \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}\\
\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3-1}\le x+1
}\Rightarrow\cases{
x+1\le \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}\\
\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}\le x-1
}\Rightarrow 2\le \sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}
$$
and $\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}$ is monotonic decreasing for $x\to\infty$.
NOTE
$$
\cases{
\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}=O_-(x)\\
\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+ 1}=O_+(x)\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{O_+(x)}{O_-(x)}=1
}
$$

Transforming the limit by $x=\frac1t$ will make it easier:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^3+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^3-1}=\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(1+t)^3+t^3}-\sqrt[3]{(1-t)^3-t^3}}t$$
Since then by L'Hospital rule the evaluation will be easy: $\frac13\cdot3-\frac13(-3)=2.$
